# Scheduling sending mail in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple case, where **once a day**, I have to loop over every entry in my mongo database and send email to every user, that **registrationDate** is over 30 days.

My code:

```
import schedule from 'node-schedule';

schedule.scheduleJob(
   '0 0 * * *',       // will occur every day at midnight
   async () => {
      await Promise.all(notifyUsers());
   },
);
```

**`notifyUsers`** function:

```
const THIRTY_DAYS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;

const allUsersMore30days = Users.find(
   {
      hasBeenReminded: false,
      registrationDate: {
         "$lt": new Date(Date.now() - THIRTY_DAYS),
      },
   },
);
```

and then:

```
const notifyUsers = () => allUsersMore30days && allUsersMore30days.map(async(user) => {
   await Users.updateOne({ id: user.id }, { "$set": { hasBeenReminded: true }});

   await transporter.sendMail(SENDING_MAIL_LOGIC);
});
```

The function is properly being called at midnight, but no mail is sent and no action is taken if any user is longer than 30 days. There are many users longer than 30 days, but still, no action is taken.

**Question**: Should I use `Promise` here? Should be the function inside `scheduleJob` async? I'm struggling with that for several days, looking for help.

Comment: Add a console.log inside notifyUsers and check if `transporter.sendMail(SENDING_MAIL_LOGIC);` is called at all, maybe `allUsersMore30days` is not truthy. Also `allUsersMore30days.map` should return a promise.

Comment: I think Users.find return a promise and instead of returning allUsersMore30days && you should return only map

Comment: @Townsheriff I think not, since no entry is modified (`hasBeenReminded` is not being set to `true`)

Comment: @ducmai _"return only map"_? What do you mean? `map` is being returned in this code sample

Comment: I meant like this return allUsersMore30days ? allUsersMore30days.map(..) : []